# 13 regressions using lm function in a while loop

Tags: r, linear-regression, finance

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

In the actual dataset I have 13 different stocks (13 x 5 = 65 columns and 135 rows)

I am trying to regress RET on mktrf, smb  and hml for each stock (ret1 , ret2 , ret3 etc.)

I'm new to R, this is my best shot at what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
df <- read.csv("stockRetFF.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

i <- 1
j <- 2
k <- 3
l <- 4
lm_results <- list()

while (i <= 13){
  lm_results[[i]] <- lm(df[,i] ~ df[,j] + df[,k] + df[,l])
  i <- i + 5
  j <- j + 5
  k <- k + 5
  l <- l + 5
}
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: It would probably be simpler if you broke the sections of 5 columns into 13 data frames within a single list. That would make it easy to use `lapply()` to generate results in a list as well. One reason your current code does not work because it quits after the third stock, `i <= 13`, but `i` is the beginning column of each block, not the number of the block. On the last block `i` should be 61.

Comment: Right, thank you. I managed to break it up into 13 different dataframes but I'm not sure how to combine them into a list and then run lapply()

Comment: Just combine them all `list(df1, df2, df3, df4, . . . )`. But you could also have created the list when you broke them out as separate data frames by generating a list of the column numbers for each block, e.g. `list(1:5, 6:10, ...)` and used that with `lapply()` to split them out.

Comment: pivot_longer, groupby, then run lm

Comment: Provide data as text and not as an image